# Is it possible to discover the name of the module being compiled during a GWT compilation

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT generator that needs to know the name of the module being compiled.

GeneratorContext does not provide this information. Only LinkerContext has a public method that exposes this, but I need this during the compilation.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers.

I really need this at compile time. I am developing a library that scans the project for files with a specific file extension (through ResourcesOracle) and generate some resources for them. I was trying to identify the module name to avoid generate resources for files that can be present on inherited modules.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the GWT Generator. Is this generator to be used as public API? If not, you could create a property file to be read with you favorite build tool. Then read it during compile time.

Comment: Does the _generator_ need to know the module name? or the generated code? In the latter case, you can use [`GWT.getModuleName()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#getModuleName%28%29) in the generated code.

Answer (score 0):

Its not available before linker time (its possible that it could be *made* available, but I can't presently speak to how viable that idea is), but it *is* available at runtime via `GWT.getModuleName()`. Since the compiler will know the name of the module, this is effectively a constant that can be placed in your code in place of this method call, so `equals` checks against `GWT.getModuleName()` or the like should be compiled out as expected.

*Nearly* any use case of needing the module name can be solved with this - checking which module is building, adding the module name to some strings in code, etc. If you have another one, consider posting the problem you are trying to solve, not the tool you think you need to solve it.